# How to get today's date as quarterly divided

Tags: java, localdate

Today's date will be given and

January, April, July, October = 1

February, May, August, November = 2

March, June, September, December = 3

should be printed. Example: december is 3rd month of quarter so answer will be 3.
Is there any better solution for this?

```
public int getValue() {
    switch (LocalDate.now().getMonthValue()) {
        case 1:
        case 4:
        case 7:
        case 10:
            return 1;
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 8:
        case 11:
            return 2;
        case 3:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 12:
            return 3;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value");
    }
```

Comment: How about `((LocalDate.now().getMonthValue() + 2) % 3) + 1`?

Comment: What about a modulo divison? Can you imagine using it in order to convert *month of year* to *month of quarter*?

Comment: Declare `Month currentMonth = Month.from(YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));` and then get your month-of-quarter value from `currentMonth.getValue() - currentMonth.firstMonthOfQuarter().getValue() + 1` (just gave 2 because May is month 2 of the 2nd quarter). It may be a bit wordy, but I consider it more high-level than a modulo operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int getValue(int month) {
    return month % 3 == 0 ? 3 : month % 3;
}
```